# VBA File/Path error when ControlSource property of checkbox form is present

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform

I faced Path/file access error when I load the form that has a checkbox with ControlSource property filled. To reproduce issue you can get [this file](https://files.fanra.ir/test_checkbox_path-file_access_error.rar) or follow steps below:

1. Create and open a blank xlsm workbook.
2. Create Userform1 and add a checkbox to it.
3. Assign value `Sheet1!A1` to ControlSource property of checkbox.
4. Add following codes to `ThisWorkbook` module:

> Private Sub Workbook_Open()
>
> UserForm1.Show
>
> End Sub

5. Save and close.
6. Open workbook. You see the form without error.
7. Without any doing, close the form and the workbook.
8. Re-open the workbook. You see Path/file access error

**EDIT**:

See the problem in screen recorded video from [here](https://files.fanra.ir/test_checkbox_path-file_access_error_video.mp4).

Comment: Try setting `ShowModal` form property to `False`...

Comment: @FaneDuru Changing ShowModal didn't affect. The issue still remains.

Comment: It does not raise any error in my case. Is the sheet where `ControlSource` changes values protected? Otherwise, it should not raise any error. If not, try it in a new workbook. You may have some corruption problems in the one you have/test it.

Comment: @FaneDuru I tested that in multiple new workbooks. You can download my sample. My test is in Excel 2010.

Comment: Do you have any code in `UserForm1` under `Sub Form_Initialize()` or `Sub Form_Activate()`?

Comment: Downloaded and tested it. Excel 365... It works without any error. Of course, after I exported its form, imported in a new workbook and make `ShowModal` `False`. If you want, I can share it... In fact, download it form [here](https://easyupload.io/bbkv6o) and test it. If you still have a problem, I am afraid your installation may be problematic, too...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon No, Whole codes what I wrote in first post. You can download the file as well.

Comment: @FaneDuru I tested your file. I changed the checkbox tick to off (false), closed the form and saved workbook. Then re-open it, I see Path/file access error.

Comment: Then, I am afraid you have a problem with your Office installation. Try testing the workbook on another computer, please.

Comment: I'm not downloading anything, posts should be self-contained.

Comment: @FaneDuru If I can I'll test it on another computer. Also, you can see the problem in screen recorded video that I added.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon My post describes the issue completely and clearly, If you reed the steps carefully.